# The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities Workaround

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am in the middle of transitioning from Teleriks OpenAccess to Entity Framework.  We have many areas throughout the application that use c# code within our queries.  In this case I see that I can change

```
_dbContext.ClientPlanHDRs.Where(cph => cph.CompanyID == GlobalVariables.CompanyID 
&& cph.ClientID == clientID && cph.ACTIVE 
&& cph.BeginEnrollment.Value.Date <= DateTime.Now.Date
&& cph.EndEnrollment.Value.Date >= DateTime.Now.Date && cph.OpenEnrollment).ToList();
```

to

```
_dbContext.ClientPlanHDRs.Where(cph => cph.CompanyID == GlobalVariables.CompanyID 
&& cph.ClientID == clientID && cph.ACTIVE 
&& cph.BeginEnrollment.Value.Date <= DbFunctions.TruncateTime(DateTime.Now.Date) 
&& cph.EndEnrollment.Value.Date >= DbFunctions.TruncateTime(DateTime.Now.Date) && cph.OpenEnrollment).ToList();
```

This type of coding is everywhere in our application.  We use c# code within queries as it was allowed.  Is there a way to get around having to change every query that does this?  A possible tool that might help or even a plugin?

Comment: How is `BeginEnrollment.Value.Date` declared?  I use `DateTime.Now.Date` (or `DateTime.Today`) in EF queries all the time.  There is no native `Date` type in .NET that I know of, only `DateTime` and `DateTimeOffset`.

Comment: I figured out i was wrong and its actually this date. I had to write it to look on the date and not just the value.date BeginEnrollment.Value.Date